# local memory as well as webservice

Tags: ios, objective-c

even after so many research i haven't found a solution for this question. I am currently working on a app which uses 3 view controllers for Registration with a log out button. the last view controller has the Register button which saves all the details of registration in a web service. But if the user has filled the two view forms and logs out. The two view filled forms field should be saved in the local memory  and wen the user logs it again the pre filled forms should load the fields saved in internal memory just to continue the Registration for webservice. Any idea how to implement this sort of functionality

Comment: Remove first line (I do not know how many negative votes i might get to this sort of question), you will surely get lesser downvotes!!!

Comment: So you want to save the user's input if they fill out all of the necessary registration information, but logout before submitting it?

Comment: You want it to persist, So you can use `NSUserDefaults` or a `plist` file.

Comment: yes u are right @ lnetiatic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, NSUserDefaults will suffice for what you need.

```
NSUserDefaults *registrationInfo = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
```

Guessing you have text fields with the info you need. So pull out the text and save to a key like this.

```
[registrationInfo setObject:self.someTextFieldName.text forKey@"firstTextField"];
```

After repeating this for every text field(use different key names though), call this `[registrationInfo synchronize];`

To pull the data out, you open the defaults again just like the first line. And to retrieve a specific key: `NSString *firstTextField = [registrationInfo objectForKey:@"firstTextField"];`

To make this easier, you can also put all of your strings in an array or dictionary, and then add that as an object in your defaults. Then you only have to set/get once.

Answer (score 1):

If you have large amount of data to save use CoreData else you NSUserDefaults to save it.

Comment: i have 10 to 15 fields  in the whole registration

Comment: NSUserDefaults will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use **PLIST** There are mainly three steps to do this.

**1) Generate .plist file.**

```
NSError *error1;
BOOL resourcesAlreadyInDocumentsDirectory;
BOOL copied1;
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath1 = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingString:@"/epub.plist"];

resourcesAlreadyInDocumentsDirectory = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:filePath1];

if(resourcesAlreadyInDocumentsDirectory == YES) {

} else {

    NSString *path1 = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingFormat:@"/epub.plist"];
    copied1 = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:path1 toPath:filePath1 error:&error1];

    if (!copied1) {
        NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to copy epub.plist. Error %@", [error1 localizedDescription]);
    }
}
```

**2) Try to read(open) it.**

```
NSMutableDictionary* dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath1];
```

**3) write data to plist file.**

```
[dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:value] forKey:@"value"];
[dict writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

This is a simple way to use it. I suggest to use .**plist file in place of NSUserDefaults**.